# Missing Date in DatePeriod Object

Tags: php, datetime

I have following script. I create a starting datetime object and an end datetime object. Then i create a dateperiod object with a 1 month date interval.
The i simply iterate through all dates.

My problem is, as you can see the output below, the iteration is missing `2015-04-01 00:00:00.000000`.

Is something wrong with my script or is it a bug?

PS: Changing the DateTimeZone doesnt change the output.

```
$start = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '31.03.2015')->setTime(0, 0);
$end = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '10.02.2016')->setTime(0, 0);

$datePeriod = new \DatePeriod($start, new \DateInterval('P1M'), $end);

var_dump($start, $end);
foreach ($datePeriod as $date) {
    var_dump($date);
}
```

**Output of var_dump($start, $end);**

```
object(DateTime)[1524]
  public 'date' => string '2015-03-31 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[1477]
  public 'date' => string '2016-02-10 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

**Output of foreach() var_dump($date);**

```
object(DateTime)[1581]
  public 'date' => string '2015-03-31 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[1438]
  public 'date' => string '2015-05-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[1581]
  public 'date' => string '2015-06-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[1438]
  public 'date' => string '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[1581]
  public 'date' => string '2015-08-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[1438]
  public 'date' => string '2015-09-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[1581]
  public 'date' => string '2015-10-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[1438]
  public 'date' => string '2015-11-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[1581]
  public 'date' => string '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[1438]
  public 'date' => string '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[1581]
  public 'date' => string '2016-02-01 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

Comment: How long is a month? This is not a bug, this is you assuming that somehow PHP will magically know that you want to get the last day of the next month with each adjustment

Comment: If you need this, work from the first day of each month, and format to display the last date of that month when you display - [Demo](https://3v4l.org/SSVIi)

Answer (score 1):

To clarify you want to just loop through every day between two date ranges? If so you can approach the problem differently.

```
$startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '31.03.2015');
$endDate   = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '10.02.2016');

while ($startDate <= $endDate) {
    // Logic here.

    $startDate->modify('+1 day');
}
```

The above will loop through all days between the two dates by a day increment,  this should suffice for now if your requirement is what I think it is?

Also you could just initialise the `DateTime` objects to whatever start/end date you require then loop through as shown above, you can increment by whatever value you need `+1 day`, `+1 week` and so on.

Just a bit of additional information for handling `DateTime`

If you want to loop through the first day of a month, to the last day of the month then it would be easier to use something like:

```
$date      = new DateTime();
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date->format('Y-m-01 00:00:00');
$endDate   = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date->format('Y-m-t 00:00:00');
```

`t` gets you the last day of a month,

`01` gets you the first day of the month